# Publisher verification for OAuth access with Microsoft Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I've been developing an app that requires access to a user's calendar on their Microsoft account. Initially, everything was functioning smoothly, and I even have a promising opportunity with a company interested in trying out my app.

However, I encountered an issue recently. Upon testing the app with a professional Microsoft account, I discovered that the login process is blocked unless the user has administrator access. This could potentially jeopardize my opportunity with the company.

In light of this, I'm now seeking a solution to overcome this obstacle. I've come across information indicating that I need to be part of the Microsoft Partner Program and obtain an MPN (Microsoft Partner Network) ID account to proceed. However, I'm currently in the process of setting up my own company, which might take up to a month.

I'm wondering if there are alternative approaches to address this verification requirement. Could it be possible to request assistance from another editor or find a workaround? Additionally, I'm curious about the timeline for the verification process once the MPN ID account is established. Is it a relatively swift procedure?

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance on how to navigate this situation effectively. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think theres a way around it. And, I guess there should not a way around it.

The main reason for the publisher verification is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/protect-against-consent-phishing